# Check all modified date of file with in last 5 day in terminal.

Tags: 14.04, command-line, lxterminal

I need to get all modified date time-stamp from last 5 days for a file in terminal, so suggest me command to check that.
I am new to Linux command programming, so help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

`find /path/to/files -mtime n` is the right way, but have a look on

```
Numeric arguments can be specified as

       +n     for greater than n,

       -n     for less than n,

       n      for exactly n.
```

So when you are interested in a period you **must** use a leading `+` or `-`:

To understand how +/- n is working examine these examples:

Suggesting `n = 3` and `now = 2016/03/15 15:49:00` (24h hour clock) then `n = 3` points to exactly one moment in time:

`2016/03/15 15:49:00` and `n = 3` leads to **`2016/03/12 15:49:00`**

Now let's see what prefix leads to which period:

```
-mtime -3   results in now-3*24h until now and the future
            (2016/03/12 15:50:00 until all days)

-mtime  3   results in now-4*24h until now-3*24h
            (2016/03/11 15:49:01 until 2016/03/12 15:49:59)

-mtime +3   results in all that is older than now-4*24h
            (2016/03/11 15:49:00 and before it)
```

So there are no overlappings between the periods resulting from the prefixes `-`,  and `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find`:

```
find /path/to/directory -mtime 5
```

Replace `/path/to/directory` with the location you want to search.

The numeric argument behind `-mtime` (here 5) is the **number of days** that passed since the file was last modified.

Note that due to how `find` rounds the time stamps, you might want to add one day to get correct results. See `man find` for more info.

```
 -atime n
     File was last accessed n*24 hours ago. When find figures out how many 
     24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is 
     ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at 
     least two days ago.
 -mtime n
     File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. See the comments
     for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of 
     file modification times.
```

Comment: you need to use -5 to find files modified in the last 5*24 hours